# Silverstripe: SwipeStripe Member/Customer record not defined

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe, swipestripe

So I'm using the SwipeStripe module as an ecommerce shop, and having issues logging member details as customer details. I'll outline the process and what i've tried so far.

- I am currently logged in as a member of my website.
- I can view, and add products to my cart.
- When I reach the checkout page, it asks me to register my details (become a member).

I have gone through the Customer.php, and OrderForm.php files. What I have discovered is:

`Customer::currentUser()` is not recognising me as a logged in user.

When I print `Member::currentUser()` it can see I am a logged in, registered member and I can print the details of that record.

`Customer::currentUser()` is as follows in the Customer.php file:

```
static function currentUser() {
    $id = Member::currentUserID();
    if($id) {
        return DataObject::get_one("Customer", "\"Member\".\"ID\" = $id");
    }
}
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me understand why `Customer::currentUser()` isn't recognising me as a logged in user?

Also, in the OrderForm.php, when I change the validation for the "register as a member" form fields (the function is called 'createFields') to `Member::currentUserID()` it recognises that I'm logged in and skips that section. It's only when it goes to save my order and customer details to the customer DB table, that it can't retrieve my email address.

Comment: The user you are logged in as, did you set them up as a Customer, or as a Member? SwipeStripe is expecting a Customer user. If you are logged in as just a Member, it might be confusing the SwipeStripe code.

Comment: Thanks for the response @3dgoo they are set up as a member. Is there anyway to have the user be both a member, and a customer with the same record? I don't want to have to set my members up with 2 accounts just to use the shop. I have set "Customers" as a child group of the "Members" group in the admin section and I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: In SwipeStripe a Customer is a Member, with extra fields and functions. A Member is not a Customer. If you want the user to be able to use the shop make sure to set them up as a Customer.

Comment: Thanks @3dgoo but how do I set them up as a customer?

Comment: One way to do that is through the front end through the SwipeStripe checkout process. Make sure you are not logged in, go through the cart and in the checkout it will set up a new Customer user.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I've used this code/method all the way up to SS 3.4.

You will need to update Aram's code to work with SS 3.x.x

https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/e-commerce-modules/show/21390

-helenclarko